# using contenteditable in a php generated table to update mysql

Tags: php, mysql, contenteditable

supposing you have a table generated via php from a mysql database,

eg,

```
 <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_sampleOA_set['concentration']; ?> </td>
    </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_sampleOA_set = mysql_fetch_assoc($sampleOA_set)); ?>
```

how would you go about using the contenteditable attribute to make the table cell editable and the edit to update the database?